# Use a .map integer as target of another map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like use the array integer value as a target value, to change attributes of another element inside it's own .map array.

I've created this menu system long-targeting sibling children, but would like a much more dry approach.

```
    // topnav items
    let ship_nav = $('.nav_primary-container li:contains("Shipping")');
    let yopo_nav = $('.nav_primary-container li:contains("Your")');
    let fopo_nav = $('.nav_primary-container li:contains("For")');
    let fugo_nav = $('.nav_primary-container li:contains("Future")');
    let comm_nav = $('.nav_primary-container li:contains("Community")');
    let env_nav = $('.nav_primary-container li:contains("Environmental")');
    let news_nav = $('.nav_primary-container li:contains("News")');

    // submenu items
    let ship_sm = $('#subnav-shipping');
    let yopo_sm = $('#subnav-yourport');
    let fopo_sm = $('#subnav-forport');
    let fugo_sm = $('#subnav-future');
    let comm_sm = $('#subnav-comm');
    let env_sm = $('#subnav-env');
    let news_sm = $('#subnav-news');


    let topNavItems = [ship_nav, yopo_nav, fopo_nav, fugo_nav, comm_nav, env_nav, news_nav];

    let subNavItems = [ship_sm, yopo_sm, fopo_sm, fugo_sm, comm_sm, env_sm, news_sm];


    //submenus
    $(topNavItems).map(function() {

      $(this).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let submenu_container = $('.nav_primary-popover-container').find('.subnav-open');

        // close already open submenu
        if ($(submenu_container).length > 0) {
          $(submenu_container).removeClass('subnav-open');
        }

        let navindex = $(this).index();

        let sm_idx = $(subNavItems).map(navindex);
        $(sm_idx).toggleClass('subnav-open');

      });

    });
```

When trying to use the array integer to target an object in another map array, console prints `... a.call is not a function`

Solution, with closing of subnav that is already open and isn't the target:

```
    //submenus
    $(topNavItems).map(function() {

      $(this).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let navindex = $(this).index();
        let sm_index = subNavItems[navindex];
        sm_index.toggleClass('subnav-open');

        let sm_opened = $('.nav_primary-popover-container').find('.subnav-open').not(sm_index);
        $(sm_opened).removeClass('subnav-open');

      });

    });
```

Comment: why you're doing  `$(topNavItems).map...`  instead of `topNavItem.map...` ?

Comment: `map()` requires a function argument and you are passing it a number. Not really clear what you are trying to do there

Comment: The outer call to `.map()` should be `.forEach()` anyway because there are no returned values.

Comment: HTML would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal map() isn't needed since you can get it right from the `subNavItems` array using the same index value

Try

```
let navindex = $(this).index();
subNavItems[navindex].toggleClass('subnav-open');
```

Comment: Beautiful. Now to get through any subNavItems that has the class and remove it if it is not the targeted one.

Comment: Easy fix .... `$('.subnav-open').not(subNavItems[navindex]).removeClass('.subnav-open')`

Comment: Oh nicely done! Already printed a solution to that but yours is more elegant in a single line.

Comment: If these subNavs are children of the top nav items...you have very much overcomplicated this by splitting them into arrays and going through all the indexing

Comment: They aren't children, but in a parent sibling children.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery [**map()**](https://api.jquery.com/map/) function itself provide the index number as its first argument of callback function. You have to use that instead of `$(this).index()`. Inside callback `this` refers the item of `topNavItems` array which is a HTML element object. So you can pass the first argument for the callback function which indicates the index number of `topNavItems` and second argument is the element of the array. Try the following codes:

```
$(topNavItems).map(function(key, item) {
    $(item).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let submenu_container = $('.nav_primary-popover-container').find('.subnav-open');

        // close already open submenu
        if ($(submenu_container).length > 0) {
            $(submenu_container).removeClass('subnav-open');
        }

        $(subNavItems[key]).toggleClass('subnav-open');
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe for jQ methods callback function parameters usually go in this order `index`, `element` .